# How to play Age of Mythology on a VM

Tags: age-of-mythology, virtualization

I've recently been hit with the desire to play old games.

Due to my past experience with old games, such as *Command & Conquer: Red Alert 2*, which usually crashes a lot under Windows 8.1, I decided to set up a *Windows XP* VM (Virtual Machine) for exactly these kinds of cases.

I then proceeded to install *Age of Mythology* on the VM, but it refused to start, saying that my graphics adapter was not supported, and with following info:

> Video Card 0: vmx_fb.dll VMware SVGA II Vendor(0x15AD) Device(0x405)

I've played more demanding games on a *Windows 7* VM before, so I know this error is just plain textbook [defeatism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defeatism).

How do I teach *Age of Mythology* to be a little bit more trusting?

Comment: Note that Age of Mythology: Extended Edition is now available on Steam and works on all versions of Windows. Could be an option for some

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Google, I found [this site](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1007766&s=960a12026f60d57fb45f3cfadf06480b), which is about playing *Age of Mythology* on Ubuntu over a Virtualbox VM.

The solution only works for Virtualbox, however, not for VMware. It still helped me find a working solution, as all I needed was to adapt a few variables.

To trick *Age of Mythology* into launching despite not recognizing the graphics adapter, you'll have to create a file in the `[AoM install directory]\gfxconfig` directory. If you installed *Age of Mythology* in its default location, that would be `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Age of Mythology\gfxconfig`.

Inside that directory, you have to create a file named: `[vendor ID]_[vendor name].gfx`. Looking at the error message:

> Video Card 0: vmx_fb.dll VMware SVGA II Vendor(0x15AD) Device(0x405)

we can tell that `[vendor ID]` is `0x15AD` and `[vendor name]` is `vmware`, so the file's name would be: `0x15AD_vmware.gfx`.

Now that the file exists, you'll need to open it with a text editing software, such as *Notepad*, which is pre-installed in pretty much every version and edition of Windows, and add following text to it:

> [config]
>   Vendor=VMware
>   defaultdevice=CyberBladeXP.gfx
>
> [knownGoodDriver]
>   Month=9
>   Day=21
>   Year=2009
>   Product=0
>   Version=0
>   SubVersion=0
>   Build=0
>
> [device]
>   0x405=CyberBladeXP,CyberBladeXP.gfx

Actually, it doesn't seem to matter much, what info is written inside. I just copy-pasted the text meant for Virtualbox, and it still worked like a charm (although I admit, I didn't try to actually play the game then). Apparently, you need to make sure the `[knownGoodDriver]` part matches your driver's date, but I think it doesn't really matter, as long as your drivers are newer than what's listed.

Unfortunately, Microsoft thought it was a good idea to hide extensions of known file types, such as `.exe` or `.txt`, so it's possible your file has a `.gfx.txt` extension and you just don't know it yet. [This Microsoft support site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/865219) tells you how to "fix" that issue. If it doesn't help, you can always [ask Google](https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+show+extensions+in+windows+xp).

---

Although this solution is limited to *Age of Mythology*, there's a good chance for it to work for other [*Ensemble Studios* games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_Studios#Games) as well.

Enjoy your [nostalgia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostalgia).

Comment: Or if you wanted to take the easy way out with Age of Empires II you could buy Age Of Empires II HD on Steam. Still, useful answer.

Comment: @tombull89 Or the recent Age of Mythology Extended Edition, which should work fine on modern OSes. Bit pricey, though.

Answer (score 3):

To build upon the existing answer.

I found that you don't have to find the date of the driver on your system. Instead use the `.gfx` file as follows with VMware (tested on VMware Workstation 10):

```
[config]
Vendor=VMware
defaultdevice=CyberBladeXP.gfx

[knownGoodDriver]
Month=0
Day=0
Year=0
Product=0
Version=0
SubVersion=0
Build=0

[device]
0x405=CyberBladeXP,CyberBladeXP.gfx
```

Also, to make this work with both the base game and the extension (The Titans), I had to copy the file from the folder `gfxconfig` into `gfxconfig2` as well.

Comment: This did the trick for me! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I used to get the same error:

```
Video Card 0: VBoxDisp.dll VirtualBox Graphics Adapter Vendor(0x80EE) Device(0xBEEF)
```

In my case I had installed Virtual Box Guest Additions in "normal mode" of Windows. The diagnostic tool of Directx (dxdiag) showed that the video card didn't support DirectX 3D acceleration.

Solution: I re-installed VB Guest Additions but in this time in "Safe mode" of Windows and when I started the game it played fine! I didn't have to create the .gfx file. Also further searching I discover that now the Graphics Adapter is totally different from what it used to be.